# How to find difference between two Joda-Time DateTimes in minutes

Tags: java, jodatime

Below is the method I wrote:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> loadNotYetInEmployee(int shift, Date date,
        int transitionVal, String type, User user) {

    DateTime datetime = new DateTime(date);
    datetime = datetime
            .plus(Period.minutes(shiftTiming.getSession1InTime()));

    List<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

    sql = SqlMapUtils.getSql("attendance.attendancestatus.latein",
            parameters);
    result = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        Date punchInTime = (Date) result.get(i).get("punchtime");
        DateTime punchTime = new DateTime(punchInTime);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now from my method you can see I have a [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object in object named `datetime` and from my result I am getting one timestamp which I am converting to jodatime `punchTime`. Now I want to find out the diff between these two dates, how do I do that?

Comment: [Minutes#minutesBetween](http://tinyurl.com/9bvfzxy)is your friend.

Comment: But this will only work if your DateTime objects are in the same TimeZone.

Comment: [`Days.daysBetween(d1, d2)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html) is the neighbour of your friend

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This will get you the difference between two DateTime objects in milliseconds:

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime();
DateTime d2 = new DateTime();

long diffInMillis = d2.getMillis() - d1.getMillis();
```

Comment: The answer by MadProgrammer should have been the Accepted Answer. Notice the simple use of `Minutes.minutesBetween`.

Comment: No I disagree, it's too wordy and unclear: "The minutes minutes between punch time date time" is worse than "second date milliseconds minus first date milliseconds"

Comment: This wil not take daylight savings into account.

Answer (score 482):

Something like...

```
DateTime today = new DateTime();
DateTime yesterday = today.minusDays(1);

Duration duration = new Duration(yesterday, today);
System.out.println(duration.getStandardDays());
System.out.println(duration.getStandardHours());
System.out.println(duration.getStandardMinutes());
```

Which outputs

```
1
24
1440
```

or

```
System.out.println(Minutes.minutesBetween(yesterday, today).getMinutes());
```

Which is probably more what you're after

Comment: Does the above take into account time zones? Or should I convert to UTC / GMT first?

Comment: @DooDah That's a good question, I "believe" that it does (as JodaTime has the concept of `LocalTime`), but I would suggest you test it and see. The question would be though, in which time zone would the resulting value be represented in?

Comment: I will test and figure this out. For me, the resulting timezone will likely be the server the code is running on. I am implementing a scheduled queue and will need to compute the amount of time between now and some future time based on a date from another time zone. I will report back what I find.

Comment: I agree, this should have been the selected answer. Its neat and simple.

Comment: Creating a new Duration object just to get a time difference just isn't cool. Imagine having to perform a time difference on a large array of date/time objects.

Comment: @AndroidDev Given the fact that it's more accurate then "manual" calculating the result, I would say it's a better solution, besides if it's "really uncool", you could just do `long diffInMinutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(fromdate, todate);` and not care

Comment: Lemme slip in `Days.daysBetween(d1, d2)` which might be helpful to some.

Answer (score 12):

Something like...

```
Minutes.minutesBetween(getStart(), getEnd()).getMinutes();
```

Comment: Fails if the start and end date are really far apart (greater than size of int)

Answer (score 6):

```
DateTime d1 = ...;
DateTime d2 = ...;
Period period = new Period(d1, d2, PeriodType.minutes());
int differenceMinutes = period.getMinutes();
```

In practice I think this will always give the same result as the answer based on `Duration`. For a different time unit than minutes, though, it might be more correct. For example there are 365 days from 2016/2/2 to 2017/2/1, but actually it's less than 1 year and should truncate to 0 years if you use `PeriodType.years()`.

In theory the same could happen for minutes because of leap seconds, but Joda doesn't support leap seconds.