# calculate difference of two JXdatepicker

Tags: java, swing, date, swingx

how to get current date and time into `JXDatePicker` and how to calculate the difference between two `JXDatePicker` in comprise to day, hour , month, minute ,second

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXDatePicker.html

Comment: The same way you would always calculate the difference between two dates, JodaTime, [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851934/how-to-find-difference-between-two-joda-time-datetimes-in-minutes/12852021#12852021)