# Find the number of months and day between date range

Tags: java

I have a start date and end date in database like below.

> start date:01/06/2014 end date:30/06/2014
>
> start date:01/07/2014 end date:30/09/2014
>
> start date:01/10/2014 end date:31/03/2015

if i enter the date range

> start date 02/06/2014
>  end date   01/02/2015

the output has to be.

```
28 days, in 1st slab date range

2 months, 29 days, in 2nd slab date range

4 months in 3rd slab date range
```

how to achieve this in java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: If you can, use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or [Java 8's reimplementation (`java.time`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-frame.html), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851934/how-to-find-difference-between-two-joda-time-datetimes-in-minutes/12852021#12852021)

Comment: post the code you tried and let us know the problem faced

Comment: I done if he enter the date within range suppose, if he enters start date:02/11/2014 end date 20/02/2015 i able to find  3 months 16 day.

Comment: Please explain how the input matches the output (what are "slabs")?

Comment: why is it `3 months 16 days` between `02/11/2014 and 20/02/2015`?

Comment: sorry typing mistake the answer is 3 months, 19 days.

Comment: why is it `3 months 19 days` between `02/11/2014 and 20/02/2015`?

Comment: start date:02/11/2014 end date :20/02/2015 this date range exits in last slab date ranges i.e start date:01/10/2014 end date:31/03/2015 this date range and it gives me 3 months 19 days.

Comment: ok, you don't understand me, lets try another way, what is the length between `1/2/2014 and 1/3/2014` and `1/3/2014 and 1/4/2014`?

Comment: `1/2/2014 and 1/3/2014` is 28 days, what length between `2/2/2014 and 2/3/2014`, also think about `1/1/2014 and 1/2/2014` (31 days)?

Answer (score 1):

This question is difficult to answer accurately. I believe this is what you really want,

```
// get the minimum of any number of dates.
private static Date getMinimum(Date... dates) {
  if (dates == null)
    return null;
  Date min = dates[0];
  for (Date d : dates) {
    if (d.compareTo(min) < 0) {
      min = d;
    }
  }
  return min;
}

// get the maximum of any number of dates.
private static Date getMaximum(Date... dates) {
  if (dates == null)
    return null;
  Date max = dates[0];
  for (Date d : dates) {
    if (d.compareTo(max) > 0) {
      max = d;
    }
  }
  return max;
}

public static String getDateDiff(Date startDate,
    Date endDate) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
  start.setTime(getMinimum(startDate, endDate));
  Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
  end.setTime(getMaximum(startDate, endDate));
  if (start.compareTo(end) < 0) {
    int monthCount = 0;
    int dayCount = 0;
    while (start.compareTo(end) < 0) {
      start.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
      if (start.compareTo(end) < 0) {
        monthCount++;
      }
    }
    start = Calendar.getInstance();
    start.setTime(getMinimum(startDate, endDate));
    start.add(Calendar.MONTH, monthCount);
    while (start.compareTo(end) < 0) {
      start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
      if (start.compareTo(end) < 0) {
        dayCount++;
      }
    }
    if (monthCount > 0) {
      sb.append(String.format("%d months",
          monthCount));
    }
    if (dayCount > 0) {
      if (sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.append(", ");
      }
      sb.append(String.format("%d days", dayCount));
    }
  } else {
    sb.append("0 days");
  }

  return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] input = { "01/06/2014-30/06/2014", //
      "01/07/2014-30/09/2014", //
      "01/10/2014-31/03/2015", //
      "02/06/2014-01/02/2015", };
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  for (String str : input) {
    String sArr[] = str.split("-");
    try {
      Date start = df.parse(sArr[0]);
      Date end = df.parse(sArr[1]);
      System.out.printf("start: %s, end: %s - diff: %s\n", sArr[0],
          sArr[1], getDateDiff(start, end));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The output is

```
start: 01/06/2014, end: 30/06/2014 - diff: 28 days
start: 01/07/2014, end: 30/09/2014 - diff: 2 months, 28 days
start: 01/10/2014, end: 31/03/2015 - diff: 5 months, 29 days
start: 02/06/2014, end: 01/02/2015 - diff: 7 months, 29 days
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check whether below code is helpful. I am using this.

public String getDifference(Date date1, Date date2){
    long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    long diffDays = difference / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    return (diffDays/30)+" months and "+(diffDays%30)+" days";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int monthsBetweenDates(Date startDate, Date endDate){

        Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
        start.setTime(startDate);
        Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
        end.setTime(endDate);

          int monthsBetween = 0;
            int dateDiff = end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)-start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);      
            if(dateDiff<0) {
                int borrrow = end.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);           
                 dateDiff = (end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+borrrow)-start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                 monthsBetween--;
                 if(dateDiff>0) {
                     monthsBetween++;
                 }
            }
            else {
                monthsBetween++;
            }      
            monthsBetween += end.get(Calendar.MONTH)-start.get(Calendar.MONTH);      
            monthsBetween  += (end.get(Calendar.YEAR)-start.get(Calendar.YEAR))*12;      
            return monthsBetween;
     }
```