# Days between two Dates

Tags: java, date, calendar, days

For some reason this is outputting a numerical value of around 16348.  When the first and last dates value are 0110 and 0201 respectively.  How come I am not getting a day value?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Project3 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  String firstDate = input.next(), lastDate = input.next();

  try {
    Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMdd").parse(firstDate);
    Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMdd").parse(lastDate); 
    System.out.println(Project3.days(date1, date2));     
  } catch (Exception e) {
    //
  } 

  }
   public static long days(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    start.setTime(startDate);
    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
    long daysBetween = 0;
    while(start.before(end)) {
        start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        daysBetween++;
    }
    return daysBetween;
 }
}
```

Comment: Calculating the difference between two dates is more than just subtracting two dates or counting the days, you should consider using an approtiate API, like JodaTime or the new Time API in Java 8, [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851934/how-to-find-difference-between-two-joda-time-datetimes-in-minutes/12852021#12852021)

Comment: Stepping through this with a debugger would have told you immediately what was happening.

Comment: Hint: 16348 days / 365 = 44.7 years. What about common date implementations is "about 45" years old?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to call [`Calendar.setTime(Date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime%28java.util.Date%29) on the `end`,

```
Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
end.setTime(endDate); // <-- like so.
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(
    MonthDay.parse( "0110" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMdd" ) ).atYear( 2017 ) ,
    MonthDay.parse( "0201" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMdd" ) ).atYear( 2017 ) 
)
```

## ISO 8601

If possible, change your text format to comply with the ISO 8601 standard. The month-day format is --MM-DD such as `--01-10` for the tenth of January.

## `MonthDay`

Use the [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) class to represent a month-day.

```
MonthDay md1 = MonthDay.parse( "--01-10" );
MonthDay md2 = MonthDay.pares( "--02-01" );
```

Or use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse(
    "0110" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMdd" )
)
```

## `LocalDate`

To calculate days, you must apply a year. Because of Leap Year and February 29th, we cannot accurately calculate elapsed days without the context of a year.

```
LocalDate ld1 = md1.atYear( 2017 );
LocalDate ld2 = md2.atYear( 2017 );
```

## `ChronoUnit`

Get elapsed days with [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html).

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( ld1 , ld2 );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).