# jodatime interval between 2 datetimes

Tags: java, jodatime, intervals

I would like to find the "interval" between a datetime A, and another latter one. 
ex.

- A) 21/09/2015 12:00:00
- B) 25/09/2015 12:00:00

interval = 4 days 0h 0m 0s

I found this post:
[How to find difference between two Joda-Time DateTimes in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851934/how-to-find-difference-between-two-joda-time-datetimes-in-minutes)

But I am wondering isn't JodaTime's `Interval` supposed to do this ?
If so, how?

Comment: what you want  to do ?

Comment: Sounds more like you're looking for [`Period`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html).

Comment: post edited tio answer your question

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, I am looking at the `Period` API and it might be so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking for an interval (which has anchors on the timeline) but for a duration which is not bound to a specific time on the timeline. Durations based on any time units are called `Period` in Joda-Time.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime ldtA = LocalDateTime.parse("21/09/2015 12:00:00", f);
LocalDateTime ldtB = LocalDateTime.parse("25/09/2015 12:00:00", f);
Period diff = new Period(ldtA, ldtB, PeriodType.dayTime());
System.out.println(PeriodFormat.wordBased(Locale.ENGLISH).print(diff)); // 4 days
```

Comment: What is the diffrence between `LocalDateTime` and plain `DateTime` ? -Why did you use localdt ?

Comment: @KoenDemonie `DateTime` is not plain and contains MORE state than `LocalDateTime` despite of its shorter name. `DateTime` is also related to a timezone while `LocalDateTime` is not. And that is the reason why I have chosen a type without timezone: Your strings don't have any offset or timezone references.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible but with some additional API usage. Take a look at this page it should help you understand Interval and how to use it appropriately.

[Joda Interval](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_interval.html)