# Difference between hours (MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS)

Tags: java

I have to implement a java program to make the difference between two hours. The problem is that my "hour pattern" is like this:

```
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

I have to consider ms, too.

I tried using joda:

```
String sDateStart = "2015/10/14 22:37:28.648";
String sDateFiish = "2015/10/14 22:39:13.573";

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");

Date dt1 = format.parse(sDateFiish);
Date dt2 = format.parse(sDateStart);


DateTime start = new DateTime(dt1);
DateTime finish = new DateTime(dt2);

System.out.println(Days.daysBetween(start, finish));
System.out.println(Minutes.minutesBetween(start, finish));
System.out.println(Seconds.secondsBetween(start, finish));
```

Is there any method to consider the ms?

Comment: you date String is of format `YYYY-MM-DD` and your trying to convert it to `SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy..` ????

Comment: What DateTime library are you using?

Comment: I followed this guide: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-calculate-date-time-difference-in-java/

Comment: You didn't follow it for the input dates.

Comment: A better question would be to understand what do you mean by "Is there any method to consider the ms?"

Comment: What was the Joda Time Library is now the Java 8 Date-Time API.  You can do with the `java.time.*` platform classes what you used to do with Joda.

Comment: [Use `Duration`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851934/how-to-find-difference-between-two-joda-time-datetimes-in-minutes). I'm out of votes!

Comment: [Here's the javadoc.](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html)

Comment: hehe its always interesting when people do not go through javadocs properly

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java API itself. In Date class we have getTime method which gives time in millisecond

> getTime()
>   Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

```
System.out.println((long)(dt1.getTime() - dt2.getTime()));
```

If you wanna continue using Joda Time API use  [Duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html). as mentioned by Sotirios Delimanolis