# Difference between two DateTime objects in minutes

Tags: java, datetime, localdate

```
===========================================================
Date_Time_from          | Date_Time_to
===========================================================
2018-06-16 02:00:00     |2018-06-18 02:00:00
2018-06-16 03:00:00     |2018-06-18 03:00:00
2018-06-16 04:00:00     |2018-06-18 04:00:00
2018-06-16 05:00:00     |2018-06-18 05:00:00
2018-06-16 06:00:00     |2018-06-18 06:00:00
==========================================================
```

I am using LocalDateTime but instead of getting the difference of 2 `DateTime`, it only calculated the time. It did not count the day.

Here's the code:

```
LocalDateTime fromdate = LocalDateTime.of(orderYear,orderMonth,orderDay,orderHour,orderMinute,orderSeconds);
LocalDateTime todate = LocalDateTime.of(deliverYear, deliverMonth, deliverDay,deliverHour,deliverMinute,deliverSeconds);
int a = fromdate.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY)-todate.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY);
```

The output of above code is zero since, in 2 hours in date_time_from equivalent to 120 mins subtracted to 2 hours in date_time_to.

Is there another way to get the total minutes and include to compute the date?

Comment: Have you tried joda time?

Comment: Use `Duration`!!!!! Possible duplicate [How to find difference between two Joda-Time DateTimes in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851934/how-to-find-difference-between-two-joda-time-datetimes-in-minutes/12852021#12852021)

Comment: @emaillenin JodaTime is in "maintenance" mode because of the inclusion of the new date/time API in Java 8+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LocalDateTime fromdate = LocalDateTime.of(orderYear,orderMonth,orderDay,orderHour,orderMinute,orderSeconds);
LocalDateTime todate = LocalDateTime.of(deliverYear, deliverMonth, deliverDay,deliverHour,deliverMinute,deliverSeconds);
Duration difference = Duration.between(fromdate, todate);
```

Then you can format it using something similar to...

```
long hours = difference.toHours();
long mins = difference.minusHours(hours).toMinutes();

// Or if you're lucky enough to be using Java 9+
//String formatted = String.format("%dhrs %02dmins", duration.toHours(), duration.toMinutesPart());
String formatted = String.format("%dhrs %02dmins", hours, mins);
```

And just to prove the point...

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        List<LocalDateTime> from = new ArrayList<>(5);
        List<LocalDateTime> to = new ArrayList<>(5);

        from.add(LocalDateTime.parse("2018-06-16 02:00:00", formatter));
        from.add(LocalDateTime.parse("2018-06-16 03:00:00", formatter));
        from.add(LocalDateTime.parse("2018-06-16 04:00:00", formatter));
        from.add(LocalDateTime.parse("2018-06-16 05:00:00", formatter));
        from.add(LocalDateTime.parse("2018-06-16 06:00:00", formatter));

        to.add(LocalDateTime.parse("2018-06-18 02:00:00", formatter));
        to.add(LocalDateTime.parse("2018-06-18 03:00:00", formatter));
        to.add(LocalDateTime.parse("2018-06-18 04:00:00", formatter));
        to.add(LocalDateTime.parse("2018-06-18 05:00:00", formatter));
        to.add(LocalDateTime.parse("2018-06-18 06:00:00", formatter));

        for (int index = 0; index < from.size(); index++) {
            LocalDateTime fromDate = from.get(index);
            LocalDateTime toDate = to.get(index);
            String difference = formatDurationBetween(fromDate, toDate);
            System.out.println(fromDate.format(formatter) + " - " + toDate.format(formatter) + " = " + difference);
        }
    }

    public static String formatDurationBetween(LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to) {
        Duration difference = Duration.between(from, to);

        long days = difference.toDays();
        difference = difference.minusDays(days);
        long hours = difference.toHours();
        long mins = difference.minusHours(hours).toMinutes();

        return String.format("%dd %dh %02dm", days, hours, mins);
    }

}
```

Outputs...

```
2018-06-16 02:00:00 - 2018-06-18 02:00:00 = 2d 0h 00m
2018-06-16 03:00:00 - 2018-06-18 03:00:00 = 2d 0h 00m
2018-06-16 04:00:00 - 2018-06-18 04:00:00 = 2d 0h 00m
2018-06-16 05:00:00 - 2018-06-18 05:00:00 = 2d 0h 00m
2018-06-16 06:00:00 - 2018-06-18 06:00:00 = 2d 0h 00m
```

You can of course make your own formatting algorithm based on your needs

Comment: Okay, so, based on the above, what do you think you might need to change (hint `Duration` has `toMinutes`, but what in the above example is "modifying" the `Duration`)?

Answer (score 3):

Is that what you asking for,

```
LocalDateTime fromDate = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 6, 16, 2, 0, 0);
LocalDateTime toDate = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 6, 18, 2, 0, 0);
long minutes = Duration.between(fromDate, toDate).toMinutes();
```

**Update**

As per the below comment leading zeros were removed since they are error prone.

Comment: This answer seems to be to the point since minutes were asked for. As an aside, while `00` works for specifying 0 minutes and 0 seconds, you’ll get into trouble once you try `08` for 8 minutes or `09` for 9 seconds, since Java perceives numbers with a prefixed 0 as [octal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). So it’s better to avoid that (unless you have a reason for intending octal numbers, of course).

Comment: @OleV.V. yeah, because god forbid we make people think for themselves or do due-dulligance to solve their problems 

Answer (score 2):

> I need the output to be in mins only. Thanks

There are two great answers already so this is just to add that while the `Duration` class is the most general and flexible for representing the difference between two date-times, there is a simpler option, [`ChronoUnit.MINUTES`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#MINUTES):

```
    LocalDateTime fromdate = LocalDateTime.of(2018, Month.JUNE, 16, 2, 0, 0);
    LocalDateTime todate = LocalDateTime.of(2018, Month.JUNE, 18, 2, 0, 0);
    long diffInMinutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(fromdate, todate);
    System.out.println(diffInMinutes);
```

Output is

> 2880