# Difference of two dates

Tags: java, date

I need to get difference between below 2 dates. Both dates are in String format.

```
String sDate1 = Thu Jun 26 13:45:32 IST 2018;
String sDate2 = Thu Jul 16 03:25:37 IST 2018;

Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(sDate1);
Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(sDate2)
long dateDiff2 = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Difference between two DateTime objects in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884294/difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-minutes/50884318#50884318); [Java SimpleDateFormat format issue with yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776787/java-simpledateformat-format-issue-with-yyyy/25777559#25777559); [Java finding difference between times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32961391/java-finding-difference-between-times/32961667#32961667)

Comment: I don't see the reasons for the downvotes, but what is your question?  Your code actually looks fine to me.  There is also a Java 8 way of doing this now.

Comment: -2
down vote
favorite

I need to get difference between below 2 dates. Both dates are in String format.

Comment: And what is your problem? It looks like you already have a difference in milliseconds.

Comment: but it is not working

Comment: @Samankumara in what way is it not working?

Comment: @Samankumara *is not working* is not an error description. Add the result you get and the expected result

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The primary reasons for the downvotes come down to the fact that the question is common enough to have a number of available answers AND you should NEVER do simply mathematical calculations on date/time values, there are too many rules governing how these calculations should be done not to use an appropriate API or library

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'll agree with you on the grounds that the question shows zero research on SO.  But, maybe the OP wrote that code himself.  Oh well, water under the bridge :-)

Comment: @Samankumara So, you have two questions.  1- How to convert a string value to a date value and 2- How to calculate the difference between those date values. Both questions are common and have been asked before

Comment: It's working now, thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between two DateTime objects in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884294/difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-minutes)

Comment: You should migrate to the newer date and time classes available in the `java.time` package. [Read more about it here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/legacy.html)

Comment: @Moia Not a duplicate of that. This Question is about moments, that Question is about `LocalDateTime` values (not moments).

Answer (score 1):

## Quote marks

You forgot the double-quote marks around your input strings.

## *java.time*

You are using terrible old classes that were outmoded years ago by the *java.time* classes.

## Parsing

Parse your input strings using `DateTimeFormatter` to get `ZonedDateTime` objects. Search Stack Overflow as this has been covered many times.

## Elapsed

To calculate elapsed hours, minutes, and seconds, pass those `ZonedDateTime` objects to the `Duration.between` method. For years-months-days, use `Period`. Search Stack Overflow as this has been covered many times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
String sDate1 = Thu Jun 26 13:45:32 IST 2018;
String sDate2 = Thu Jul 16 03:25:37 IST 2018;

Date d1= new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(sDate1);
Date d2= new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(sDate2); 
long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
System.out.println("Time in seconds: " + diffSeconds + " seconds.");
System.out.println("Time in minutes: " + diffMinutes + " minutes.");
System.out.println("Time in hours: " + diffHours + " hours.");
```

Or you can use TimeUnit:-

```
long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diff );
long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff );
long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diff );
```

Comment: These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. Poor advice in 2018.

Comment: I am agree with you but for bigners it is right way to do other wise he can use jodaTime also.

Comment: No, those classes are a *terrible* thing to show beginners, with a wretched design and awful hacks that will confound anyone trying to learn programming and OOP. And the *Joda-Time* project is now in maintenance mode, with its inventor having moved on to create *java.time*.