# Date validation for booking system

Tags: java, date

I am trying to set an expiry date for the user's cancellation in my booking system project and I have tried this code but it is not working and it is not logically correct. Can anyone help me in getting the idea to implement this feature for my project?

```
    Date expiryDate = new Date().after(startDate) -7 
    if(startDate.before(expiryDate))
```

The idea is that the user should not be able to cancel the reservation if the expiryDate is close to one week before the startDate of the flight. In real-world we see that we can not cancel an order if it is shipped and passes 24 hours after we placed it.

Comment: Consider getting the Date object from a Calendar since the Date constructor is deprecated.

Comment: Could you include a sample input with expected output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851934/how-to-find-difference-between-two-joda-time-datetimes-in-minutes I believe, you can find a solution for your question here.

Comment: The startDate will be the user input

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find difference between two Joda-Time DateTimes in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851934/how-to-find-difference-between-two-joda-time-datetimes-in-minutes)

Comment: @lainatnavi. Thank you for your replies, I have reviewed your answers and got the idea.

Comment: @dmrcn  Thank you for your replies, I have reviewed your answers and got the idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) instead of Date as it is now depreciated.

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2020, 05, 01);
LocalDate expDate = LocalDate.of(2020, 04, 01);

if (startDate.minusWeeks(1).isBefore(expDate)) {
    System.out.println("No problem here");
} else {
    System.out.println("Cant cancel");
}
```

Here, the check is made to see whether the start date minus a week is before the expiration date. If yes then the user can cancel the ticket, else he can't.

Comment: Thank your answer is really close to what I need. I upvoted you

Comment: Glad to help! Thanks @OleV.V.